# The Best Way to Redirect Old Url to New Url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect

I changed my web page url from classic type to SEF url type. There is a problem. When I try to add my new urls on google directory, it does not add them. When I check my urls on google, I just see my old classic urls (like www.sitename.com/detail.php?id=1).

I add a meta on new and old pages

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.sitename.com/detail-<?php echo $id."-".$seo_url;?>"/>
```

but it does not still solve my problem.

On .htaccess I add a query string manually for my new urls like these

```
RewriteRule ^detail-(\d+)-\w+/? details.php?id=$1**&seoUrl=1** [NC,L]
```

and on php page I check it

```
if(!isset($_GET['seoUrl'])){
    <?php
// PHP permanent URL redirect
header("Location: http://www.sitename.com/detail-".$id."-".$seo_url, true, 301);
exit();
?>
}
```

I wonder that, Is there another pratic way to redirect 301 for the new urls on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your 301 redirects actually work (in doubt close the browser and reopen it to get rid of its redirect cache).
If everything is fine, give Google a bit time. It might take a few days until urls are changing, and probably also not all at once but more over time.

Comment: thanks for your comment @smichaelsen, can ping services be useful to shorten the process?